# Parsing a C string literal in shell

Tags: shell-script

I have a valid C string literal that I would like to convert to its actual representation.  Sadly the %b conversion specifier for printf does not define escapes for ? ' and ", which are all valid in a C string.

Right now I have a small C program that I am using to perform the conversion, but I would prefer if I could do everything with the standard POSIX tools.

I'd like this to work with just the POSIX tools (so no GNUisms), and possibly bash, if needed, though sh is preferred.

Comment: Can you provide an example string you have trouble converting?

Comment: What shell do you mean by "sh"?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I mean the POSIX bourne shell standard, which dash, ksh and bash are all largely supersets of. (Bash has some incompatibilities, but they go away if it is invoked with "sh" as argv[0])

Comment: @EricRenouf consider "\\" which is a string containing only a single backslash and "\\\"" which is a string containing a backslash and a quote.  One thought I had after posting this was using awk with a backslash as the record separator.  That would be very doable and only slightly less confusing than my fairly straightforward C program.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way to do it in awk; it's a bit ugly though, so if someone has a better solution, I'm interested.  This will work on all valid C strings but doesn't handle all cases of invalid strings (e.g. \q where q is an invalid character to follow a backslash just consumes the character):

```
function hexnumber(str,  ret, n, k)
{
    n = length(str)
    ret = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        c = substr(str, i, 1)
        c = tolower(c)
        # index() returns 0 if c not in string,
        # includes c == "0"
        k = index("123456789abcdef", c)

        ret = ret * 16 + k
    }
    return ret;
}

function octnumber(str,  ret, n, k)
{
    n = length(str)
    ret = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        c = substr(str, i, 1)
        # index() returns 0 if c not in string,
        # includes c == "0"
        k = index("1234567", c)

        ret = ret * 8 + k
    }
    return ret;
}


BEGIN { RS="\\" ; notQuoted = 0}
#{ print $0 ; next}
NR == 1 {
    if(match($0,/^"/)) {
        split($0,matches,"\"")
        printf("%s",matches[2]);
        if(match($0,/^"[^"]*"/)) {
            exit 0;
        }
        next
    } else {
        exit 1;
    }
}

#This will happen on the 2nd (and subsequent) consecutive backslash
/^$/ {
    if (notQuoted) {
        notQuoted = 0
    } else {
    notQuoted = 1
    printf("\\")
    next
    }
}
notQuoted == 1 {
    if(match($0,/([^"]*)"/))
    {
        split($0,matches,"\"")
        printf("%s",matches[1])
        exit 0
    }
    printf("%s",$0);
    next
}
# If we reach here, then the first character is part of a backslash escape
{
    first = substr($0,1,1);
    rest = substr($0,2);

    if(first == "a") printf("\a")
    else if(first == "b") printf("\b")
        else if(first == "f") printf("\f")
        else if(first == "n") printf("\n")
        else if(first == "r") printf("\r")
        else if(first == "t") printf("\t")
        else if(first == "v") printf("\v")
        else if(first == "\"") printf("\"")
        else if (first == "x") {
            second = substr(rest,1,1);
            third = substr(rest,2,1);
            if(match(third,/[1234567890ABCDEFabcdef]/)) {
                printf("%c",hexnumber(second third)+0);
                rest = substr(rest,3);
            }
            else {
                printf("%c",hexnumber(second)+0);
                rest = substr(rest,2);
            }
        }
        else if (match(first,/[01234567]/)) {
            second = substr(rest,1,1);
            third = substr(rest,2,1);
            fourth = substr(rest,3,1);
            if(match(second third fourth,/^[01234567]*$/)) {
                printf("%c",octnumber("0" first second third fourth)+0);
                rest = substr(rest,length(first second third fourth));
            }
            else if(match(second third,/^[01234567]*$/)) {
                printf("%c",octnumber(first second third)+0);
                rest = substr(rest,length(first second third));
            }
            else if(match(second,/^[01234567]*$/)) {
                printf("%c",octnumber(first second)+0);
                rest = substr(rest,length(first second));
            }
            else {
                printf("%c",octnumber(first)+0);
            }
        }

    if(match(rest,/([^"]*)"/))  # this comment fixes vim's syntax matching " 
    {
        split(rest,matches,"\"")
        printf("%s",matches[1])
        exit 0
    }

    printf("%s",rest);
}
```

Comment: Just noticed I'm using a GNUism in this (3rd argument to match); I'll rework and edit.